# A Question Regarding Productive Sets in the Koepke-Koerwien System SO (Sets of Ordinals) 

Tags: mathematical-philosophy, set-theory, infinite-time-computability

In their paper "The Theory of Sets of Ordinals" ([arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502265)), Koepke and Koerwien propose a theory SO axiomatizing the class of sets of ordinals in a model of ZFC and show that SO and ZFC are bi-interpretable.  They also define *-recursiveness over SO which generalizes the ordinary recursive functions from omega to Ord, and show that the *-recursive sets       (i.e. the *-definable sets) form the smallest inner model of SO; SOrd*, and that SOrd*=L.  Considering that SOrd* is the smallest inner model of SO and that *-recursion generalizes the ordinary recursive functions from omega to Ord, it seems reasonable to assume that one can define productive sets of ordinals in nearly the same manner as in ordinary recursion theory, where one is defining productive sets of finite ordinals.  Of course (in analogy with ordinary recursion theory), the productive sets of ordinals will not be *-definable, and therefore will not be constructible.  Are there aguments against the existence of productive sets of ordinals, and, more importantly, in what way are productive sets of ordinals (if they exist) related to 0-sharp?

Comment: note:  '-definable should be *-definable 'SOrd' should be SOrd* in my question 

Comment: It should also be noted that 'SOrd' should have an asterisk at the upper right-hand corner and ' -definable' should have a centered asterisk before the '-definable' as in the Koepke-Koerwien paper.

Comment: Also, scratch the 'emphasized text' from the question--that was unintentional.

Comment: @Thomas You can still modify your question.

Comment: @The User:  Thanks.  The problems I mentioned in my comments have already been modified.  As regards content or tone, is there anything you feel should be modified? 

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a productive *set* of ordinals. When I try to generalize the idea from recursion theory, I arrive at a productive *class* of ordinals. Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @Francois: Perhaps I should ask you, what is the reasoning behind your comment.  I am assuming (a bad thing to do, I know...) that since SO is axiomatizing the class of sets of ordinals the generalization of the notion of productiveness for SO will be a set, not a proper class.  I am not dogmatic on that point.  I am willing to learn, if you are willing to teach....

Comment: @Francois:  Since you have not responded to my comment (and perhaps with good reason, too, if it is something you think I should already know...), I will offer up a possible line of reasoning (at the risk of this line of reasoning being a 'straw man', so to speak...) that would make productivity in SO a proper class.  Here goes:  the *-recursive sets form the smallest inner model of SO (the model being the 'universe' of sets of ordinals).  Since the productive 'object' ( I call it an object because it is to be determined whether it is to be a proper class or set,

Comment: and the term 'object' seems to me to be a neutral term), if one takes the definition and theorem directly from ordinary recursive function theory, cannot be generated from the *-recursive functions, will lie outside the given inner model.  Therefore, it is not a 'set' relative to the given inner model and therefore relative to the given inner model, a proper class.  Is this essentially your line of reasoning? Please let me know.